# How to create (set) data to Firestore using AngularFire?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm following the [AngularFire Quickstart tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/install-and-setup.md). I got Read working, which displays the data from my Firestore database in the Angular view. I'm stumped how to get Create (`set`) working.

My `app.component.html` displays a little text form field with a `Submit` button, and the displays the values in the Firestore database:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name">
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

My `app.component.ts` file has a function `onSubmit()` that executes when the user clicks the `Submit` button. It logs the name that the user entered in the text form field. The next line throws this error:

```
TS2339: Property 'firestore' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

23     this.firestore.collection('items').doc('item').set({name: this.name}); // error is here
```

Here's my `app.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  items: Observable<any[]>;
  constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items = firestore.collection('items').valueChanges();
  }

  name: string | null = null;

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.name);
    this.firestore.collection('items').doc('item').set({name: this.name}); // error is here
    return // return what?
  }
}
```

This is the same pattern as the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) tutorial:

```js
export class HeroService {

  constructor(private logger: Logger) {  }

  getHeroes() {
    this.logger.log('Getting heroes ...');
    return HEROES;
  }
}
```

My `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// Firebase
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The view:

[image]

And my Firestore database:

[image]

Comment: `this.firestore` i think you have seen your self blind. probably the IDE is trying to use namespace firestore. in your onSubmit function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is related to TypeScript.  I believe best-practice, in this case, would be for you to use the `private` access modifier in front of `firestore: Firestore` while injecting it into the constructor of the component or service where you are using it, in your case *app.component.ts*.

The `private` access modifier does a couple things:

1. It makes the property a member of the class (similar to if you had declared the property in you class `firestore: any;`)
2. It makes the property '*private*', only available in the class but not available in the template (during development - not enforced in production).

```js
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
  this.items = firestore.collection('items').valueChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer works but I don't understand why it works. Playing around, all three of these work:

```js
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
```

```js
constructor(protected firestore: AngularFirestore) {
```

```js
constructor(public firestore: AngularFirestore) {
```

This doesn't work:

```js
constructor(firestore: AngularFirestore) {
```

According to the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#public),

```
Because public is already the default visibility modifier, you don’t ever need to write it on a class member, but might choose to do so for style/readability reasons.
```

That's clearly wrong. The `Read` function works without specifying `public`, `private`, or `protected`, but the `Update` function only works when `public`, `private`, or `protected` is specified.

I'll play around with `Create` and `Delete`. Then I'll post another question about this TypeScript behavior.