# Adding firestore to Angular typescrit error 2448

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm adding Firestore to an existing angular project but I have a TS error when trying to ad dit to the constructor with the documentation code:

```
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

  constructor(db: Firestore) {
    const collection: any = collection(db, 'songs');
    this.songs$ = collectionData(collection);
  }

TS error: Block-scoped variable 'collection' used before its declaration.ts(2448)
Type 'Observable<DocumentData[]>' is missing the following properties from type '{ new (subscribe?: ((this: Observable<Song[]>, subscriber: Subscriber<Song[]>) => TeardownLogic) | undefined): Observable<Song[]>; prototype: Observable<...>; create: (...args: any[]) => any; }': prototype, create ts(2739)
```

The firestore version: "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1"
And the ts version: typescript": "~4.7.2"

I don't understand how to get around this, and haven't been able to fin any answers on this specific issue.

Comment: I have a feeling Typescript thinks collection (the declared const) is the same as collection (the method). If you name your collection anything else (const myCollection, for example) does the issue still occur?

Comment: thanks, the collection issue is indeed fixed with your comment, but the second ts error is stil there

Answer (score 1):

Rename the `collection` variable to something else;

```js
import { Firestore, collectionData, collection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

  constructor(db: Firestore) {
    const coll: any = collection(db, 'songs');
    this.songs$ = collectionData(coll);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this:

import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import 'firebase/firestore';

Also check on:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Here is other link solution almost related:

[How to create (set) data to Firestore using AngularFire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260112/how-to-create-set-data-to-firestore-using-angularfire)